# How do I find the value of this sort of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series of the form $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^k k$$

I come across it using generating functions to find an expectation for the geometric distribution. I was wondering what's the easiest way to evaluate series of this form. More generally $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty p^k k \quad p \in (0,1)$$

Thanks

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) a very similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am renaming $p$ to $x$. Call your series $f(x)$. Divide your series by $x$, which gives
$$
f(x)/x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}.
$$
An antiderivative of this is
$$
G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}.
$$
Now what you want is
$$
f(x) = xG'(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
$$

Comment: grr, made some errors. editing now.... should be correct; check me! wolfram alpha agrees for x = 5/6 that you should get 30.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense, didn't consider differentiating the closed form. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^k=\frac1{1-p}\tag{$|p|<1$}$$
So:
$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}p}\frac1{1-p}=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}p}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^{k-1}=\frac1p\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^k\implies\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kp^k=\frac p{(1-p)^2}$$